# Building a Visual Studio Code extension for framework support

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

I have a custom framework where the files are arranged by the classes. So; component.mail.digital will have a pathing of src/component/mail/digital.js and component.mail.physical would be located at src/component/mail/physical.js. Each step along the way has a class associated with the file that extends from the previous. So; mail extends component, digital extends mail. So physical and digital share the same subclasses/functionality.

All the code is compiled into one large JavaScript file so there is no need to use require or such to link the files together (which would normally give auto completions and JSDoc support)

With this framework, I am wanting to write a Visual Studio Code extension to give me suggestions for auto complete and enable JSDoc support in showing types for things like parameters and return values. Auto complete will work for the same component in the file but when I instantiate a new object in another file I lose typing completely.

I looked into the VSCode extension templates but am confused on which would be the best to start with, or what this problem would be classified as.

Comment: None of the templates is complex enough to get you started on such a project. Try to dig into the source code an existing JavaScript related extension (many of them are open source), such as Angular/React, and you can then follow their patterns.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.